# Approximate entity search

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there anyway to do approximate search (e.g. with n-grams) of entities with doctrine2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Of the entities themselves (post-retrieval) or of the persisted content (pre-retrieval)?

Comment: I think pre-retrieval. I have a large database of artists (in this case) and I want the user to be able to search for them in a bit of a "forgiving" way, if you know what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the [FOQElasticaBundle](http://knpbundles.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle) which offers this (and a whole lot more) functionality!